# Typescript inject and arguments in class

Tags: typescript, inject, inversifyjs

I use InversifyJS and container.

I want inject **templateEngine** and pass **args** (*host, port, etc...*) in constructor.

```
const container = new Container();
container.bind<MailerInterface>(TYPES.Mailer).to(NodeMailer);
```

And my **Mailer** class:

```
import * as nodemailer from "nodemailer";
import {TemplateEngineInterface} from "../../Domain/TemplateEngine/TemplateEngineInterface";
import TYPES from "../../../../config/inversify.types";
import {inject, injectable, named} from "inversify";

@injectable()
export class NodeMailer implements MailerInterface {

    private transporter: any;
    private templateEngine: TemplateEngineInterface;

    constructor(
        @inject(TYPES.TemplateEngine) templateEngine: TemplateEngineInterface,
        host: string,
        port: number,
        secure: boolean,
        username: string,
        password: string
    ) {

        this.templateEngine = templateEngine;

        this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: host,
            port: port,
            secure: secure,
            auth: {
                user: username,
                pass: password
            }
        });

    }

}
```

How I can pass arguments in constructor with inject or others methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

## A) Inject the config

```
constructor(
    @inject(TYPES.TemplateEngine) templateEngine: TemplateEngineInterface,
    @inject(TYPES.MailerConfig) @named("host") host: string,
    @inject(TYPES.MailerConfig) @named("port") port: number,
    @inject(TYPES.MailerConfig) @named("secure") secure: boolean,
    @inject(TYPES.MailerConfig) @named("username") username: string,
    @inject(TYPES.MailerConfig) @named("password") password: string
) {
```

The type is just:

```
const TYPES = { MailerConfig: Symbol.for("MailerConfig") }
```

And the bindings:

```
type MailerConfig = string|boolean|number;

container.bind<MailerConfig>(TYPES.MailerConfig)
         .toConstantValue("localhost")
         .whenTargetNamed("host");

container.bind<MailerConfig>(TYPES.MailerConfig)
         .toConstantValue(2525)
         .whenTargetNamed("port");

container.bind<MailerConfig>(TYPES.MailerConfig)
         .toConstantValue(true)
         .whenTargetNamed("secure");

container.bind<MailerConfig>(TYPES.MailerConfig)
         .toConstantValue("root")                                         
         .whenTargetNamed("username");

container.bind<MailerConfig>(TYPES.MailerConfig)
         .toConstantValue("toor")                                    
         .whenTargetNamed("password");
```

### Tip: Reducing boilerplate

If you are going to do this, I recommend creating helpers to reduce the required boilerplate.

#### Bindings

```
type MailerConfig = string|boolean|number;

const bindMailerConfig = (ctr: Container, key: string, val: MailerConfig) =>
        ctr.bind<MailerConfig>(TYPES.MailerConfig)
       .toConstantValue(key)
       .whenTargetNamed(val);

bindMailerConfig(container, "localhost", "host");
bindMailerConfig(container, 2525, "port");
bindMailerConfig(container, true, "secure");
bindMailerConfig(container, "root", "username");
bindMailerConfig(container,"toor", "password");
```

#### Decorators

```
const injectNamed = (typeId: any) => (name: string) =>
    (target: any, targetKey: string, index?: number) => {
        inject(typeId)(target, targetKey, number);
        named(name)(target, targetKey, number);
    };

const injectMailerConfig = injectNamed(TYPES.TemplateEngine);

constructor(
    @inject(TYPES.TemplateEngine) templateEngine: TemplateEngineInterface,
    @injectMailerConfig("host") host: string,
    @injectMailerConfig("port") port: number,
    @injectMailerConfig("secure") secure: boolean,
    @injectMailerConfig("username") username: string,
    @injectMailerConfig("password") password: string
) {
```

## B) Two-step initialization

```
@injectable()
export class NodeMailer implements MailerInterface {

    private transporter: any;
    private templateEngine: TemplateEngineInterface;

    constructor(
        @inject(TYPES.TemplateEngine) templateEngine: TemplateEngineInterface,
    ) {
        this.templateEngine = templateEngine;
        this.transporter = null;
    }

    public initialize(host, port, secure, username, password) {
        if (this.transporter) {
            return this.transporter;
        }
        this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: host,
            port: port,
            secure: secure,
            auth: {
                user: username,
                pass: password
            }
        });
        return this.transporter;
    }

    public send() {
        if (this.transporter === null) {
            throw new Error("You must invoke initialize!");
        }
        // ...
    }

}
```

The two-step initialization can play nicely with a [factory](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/factory_injection.md).

Comment: Thanks, it works! But you have forgot `.bind` after container in first example ;)

Comment: I have added "bind" Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Also added a recommendation to reduce the amount of code that you need to write

Comment: Thanks very much Remo !